# Bifurcating the data using Regular expression in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to understand Regular expressions in R. So, I have column (FileName2) of datatable(df) which have strings of different patterns, and I have to understand each pattern in the string and give it a name, like an identifier, so that same patterns can be identified by the identifier. The name of the identfier has to in another column within the same datatable. I have the following 3 different patterns :
1. String Name : Modifc10 or can be  modifc1 : first five characters are fixed, next is an alphabet fixed, next can be one or two numbers. Lets take this as identifier one.
2. String Name : modifcwi12 or modifcfl1: first five characters are fixed, next three alphabets are fixed, next can be one or two numbers.Lets take this as identifier two.
3.String Name : MODIFSW :first five characters are fixed, next three or 2 are alphabets, and not numbers.Lets take this as identifier three.

```
i/p:
FileName2
MODIFC1
MODIFC10
MODIFC2
modifcfl1
MODIFCS
modifcWA1
modifcWI10
modifcWI7
MODIFS7
modifsfl1
modifsWI1
modifsWI10
modifsWI2
```

I want to use to regular expression to do this. I was trying to do this >>

```
df1 <- df[FileName2 %like% '(?i)modif\\w\\d',Identifier := 'One']
df2 <- df1[FileName2 %like% '(?i)modif\\w\\w\\w\\d',Identifier := 'Two']
df3 <- df2[FileName2 %like% '(?i)modif\\w',Identifier := 'Third']
```

But, its not giving the accurate results. I'm pretty sure, I'm not using the correct regular expression or the correct way to do this. Please let me know the efficient way to do this.

O/p should be like :

```
 FileName2    Identifier
    MODIFC1      One    
    MODIFC10     One
    MODIFC2      One
    modifcfl1    Two
    MODIFCS      Three
    modifcWA1    Two
    modifcWI10   Two
    modifcWI7    Two
    MODIFS7      One
    modifsfl1    Two
    modifsWI1    Two
    modifsWI10   Two
    modifsWI2    Two
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note that based on your expected output there is a mistake in rule 3; `MODIFCS` has the first five characters fixed, with only 2 characters following (instead of 3 as per your rule).**

I assume that for rule 3, `"modif"`/`"MODIF"` can be followed by 2 *or* 3 characters.

We can use `dplyr::case_when` with `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(Identifier = case_when(
        str_detect(tolower(Filename2),"^modif[a-z]\\d{1,2}$") ~ "One",
        str_detect(tolower(Filename2),"^modif[a-z]{3}\\d{1,2}$") ~ "Two",
        str_detect(tolower(Filename2),"^modif[a-z]{2,3}$") ~ "Three"
    ))
#    Filename2 Identifier
#1     MODIFC1        One
#2    MODIFC10        One
#3     MODIFC2        One
#4   modifcfl1        Two
#5     MODIFCS      Three
#6   modifcWA1        Two
#7  modifcWI10        Two
#8   modifcWI7        Two
#9     MODIFS7        One
#10  modifsfl1        Two
#11  modifsWI1        Two
#12 modifsWI10        Two
#13  modifsWI2        Two
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Filename2
    MODIFC1
MODIFC10
MODIFC2
modifcfl1
MODIFCS
modifcWA1
modifcWI10
modifcWI7
MODIFS7
modifsfl1
modifsWI1
modifsWI10
modifsWI2", header = T)
```

Comment: Maurits Evers, the regex did worked, and thank you for pointing out the mistake, as for 3 rule there is no numbers followed, the rule is first five characters fixed, remaining can be 2 or n number of alphabets. I will edit my question. One more thing , lets us suppose if the pattern is that we have n number of alphabets in starting than we have have n  number of alphabets, then the regex would be the following > ^(?i)[a-z]*\\d*$, right? Let me know if this is wrong ?